# Mysql query using dates between now and last week

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, between

So I am trying to get results from the database from today's date and 7 days ago but what I am doing seems to be wrong as I keep receiving a fatal error

> Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAYS GROUP BY logins.unique_id ORDER BY' Stack trace: #0 mysqli->query('SELECT SUM(DIST...', 1) #1 {main} thrown

```
  <?php //get info for scores in the league
             if ($result = $link->query("SELECT SUM(DISTINCT step_count.steps) as total,  logins.nickname, MAX(step_count.steps) as maxsteps, ROUND(AVG (DISTINCT step_count.steps)) as average, logins.Email as email
                FROM step_count
                INNER JOIN logins on
                  step_count.unique_id=logins.unique_id
              WHERE logins.unique_id='$unique_id' AND step_count.date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAYS
                GROUP BY logins.unique_id
                ORDER BY `total` DESC
              ", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT))

              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
```

After updating the column, I am still receiving the same fatal error

Comment: I guess your usage of `BETWEEN` is wrong, since im guessing your `unique_id` is not formatted as "YYYY-MM-DD"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also to recieve the data between today and 7 days ago you need to use `DATE_SUB` so the last part of your query would be:

```
step_count.date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE()
```

And your `GROUP BY` should be:

```
GROUP BY logins.nickname, email
```

Answer (score 2):

You have syntax issue here, you are missing a column before `BETWEEN`

```
logins.unique_id='$unique_id' BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAYS
```

The correct syntax of `BETWEEN` is

```
<column_name> BETWEEN <value1> AND <value2>
```

So, It should be

```
logins.unique_id='$unique_id' AND <date_column> BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

And, use [`DATE_ADD`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) instead to add specific number of days.

Comment: I don't want to use a date from the column, I would like to use the date it would be on that day, if that makes sense?

Comment: @nobody I understand, but there should be something to compare . right ?

Comment: @nobody days between what ?? that is the syntax of `BETWEEN`. You can't avoid that.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is receive stats from a certain user between today's date and 7 days ago so that they can view last weeks and this weeks stats

Comment: @nobody so, how would you classify todays data ?? you should have some column to store date time right ? Same column, you need to put there.

Comment: @nobody to do that you need to know when the stats got entered, otherwise there is now way to identify the date. That means as Ravi said, that you need an additional column where the date the stats got entered gets stored.

Comment: Oh, my mistake! On the step_count table, I have an column for date which would be used

Comment: @nobody I'm not sure, but if that is the only date column then yes.

Comment: I've updated the question slightly as I am still receiving the same error

Comment: @nobody what is the error ?? you need share to understand, if it is related. If not, then you need to post new question to avoid confusion for future reader

Comment: I'm receiving the same error as before which is stated above in my question

Comment: @nobody I can see you are doing so many things in your `SELECT` like `SUM`, `AVG`,  `ROUND` as naive programmer, I would suggest to go step by step. First write simple SELECT and then start adding group by and then `SUM` .. so on.. It is very hard to debug your problem until I have the access to your system and data

Comment: @nobody probable hint : group by column list should match with SELECT. Rest, you can debug your SQL as I mentioned in earlier comment